# SonarQube Pull Request analysis is scanning entire repo instead of changes part of the commit [Using GITHUB Actions]

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops

workflow.yml

```yaml
name: SCA-TEST0306 - DIFF ONLY
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - TEST-0306

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:      
    - name: Checkout pull request branch
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
        
    - name: Fetch repository
      run: git fetch
        
    - name: Get diff of code changes
      run: git diff --name-only origin/${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }} -- ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }} > files_changed.txt
    
    - name: Sonar Scan
      uses: docker://sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
      env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
```

In properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=**********
sonar.exclusions=force-app/main/default/staticresources/**, force-app/main/default/contentassets/**, lib/**, config/**, LICENSE/**, Release Folders/**, scripts/**, **/.png**/.jgp,**/.jpeg,**/.jar,**/.svg,**/.tar,**/.zip
sonar.inclusions=$(cat files_changed.txt | tr '\n' ',')
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS="-Xmx3062m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m"
```

During scan it says:

```
INFO: SCM collecting changed files in the branch (done) | time=224ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO:   Included sources: $(cat files_changed.txt | tr '
' ', ')
INFO:   Excluded sources: force-app/main/default/staticresources/**, force-app/main/default/contentassets/**, lib/**, config/**, LICENSE/**, Release Folders/**, scripts/**, **/.png**/.jgp, **/.jpeg, **/.jar, **/.svg, **/.tar, **/.zip
INFO:   Excluded sources for coverage: sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*.*
INFO: 0 files indexed
INFO: 250910 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
```

Hi Everyone,
Can you please help me where I am going wrong ?

My goal is to do analysis on changes part of the commit only on my PR

Comment: Properties file looks like this:
sonar.projectKey=Repo_Name

sonar.exclusions=force-app/main/default/staticresources/**, force-app/main/default/contentassets/**, lib/**, config/**, LICENSE/**, Release Folders/**, scripts/**, **/.png**/.jgp,**/.jpeg,**/.jar,**/.svg,**/.tar,**/.zip

sonar.inclusions=$(cat files_changed.txt | tr '\n' ',')

SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS="-Xmx3062m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pull request analysis is not available in Sonarqube 5.1 also, and it's not available in the community edition. You need at least the Developer edition.